# Let $T$ be the centroid of a triangle $ABC$, and let $P$ be the midpoint of the side $\overline{AC}$. The line containing the point $T$ parallel to th

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangle-centres

Question : Let $T$ be the centroid of a triangle $ABC$, and let $P$ be the midpoint of the side $\overline{AC}$. The line containing the point $T$ parallel to the line $BC$ intersects the side $\overline{AB}$ at the point $E$. Prove that the equality $\angle AEC = \angle PTC$ is true if and only if $\angle ACB=90^{\circ}$.

My attempt : [image]
$\angle EOT =\angle BOC, ET\left | \right | BC,  
\Rightarrow \angle TEO=\angle OCB. 
\Rightarrow \Delta EOT \sim \Delta OCB. 
\Rightarrow \frac{EO}{OC} =\frac{TO}{OB}. And \angle EOB=\angle TOC. 
\Rightarrow \Delta EBO \sim \Delta TOC.
\Rightarrow \angle BEO=\angle OTC. 
\Rightarrow 180^{\circ}-\angle BEO=180^{\circ}-\angle OTC. 
\Rightarrow \angle AEC=\angle PTC.$

I have tried like this which is not requiring $\angle ACB=90^{\circ}$.
But in the question we have to prove that $\angle AEC = \angle PTC$ is true if and only if $\angle ACB=90^{\circ}$.
Can you please help me to prove it in the right way.
So many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1:

> Angle condition: $\angle AEC = \angle PTC$ is equivalent to $\angle BEC = \angle BTC$ and this is equivalent to $C,B,E,T$ being concyclic.

Hint 2:

> Deduce that $DA = DB =DC$.

Hint 2':

> In reverse, deduce that $TC =EB$ so $CBET$ is isosceles trapezoid...

Comment: Thank you sir, if $\angle ACB = 90^{\circ}, then DA=DB=DC. But how to proceed to C, B E, T is concyclic?

Comment: I have understood.  Thanks giving is insufficient.  Take my respect.